# Firebase database dependency crashes app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write to my DB with the following "[Set up Firebase Realtime Database for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)" example but the app crashes on startup.

It's seems because the dependency:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
```

The crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.giat.myapplication, PID: 3874
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzeq(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzalp; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzalp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalp' appears in /data/data/com.example.giat.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-database-9.2.1_b22e7bdbdba6ace0ee1e94f163c76d1f75b59f7e-classes.dex)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1702)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1665)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4988)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4923)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

MY App build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.giat.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Did you also follow these other [setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)?

Comment: yes. I did everything as they said

Comment: Try updating the dependencies to use same version for firebase libs. Make both either 9.4.0 or 9.2.1.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This problem is caused by use of inconsistent Firebase library versions.  Update your build dependencies to consistently use version 9.4.0.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for being so on top of Firebase questions @qbix. Much appreciated!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: You're welcome.  It's educational and satisfying.  Sometimes I wish it wasn't so much fun.  I should be focusing on fixing my own problems!

Comment: thanks! it's working now :)
but I wonder why they don't mention this point(or just I missed it)

Comment: @danielgi: I haven't seen it documented anywhere, but it's always best to use the same version of the libraries.  When a new version of Google Play Services is released, all the library versions increase together.

Comment: actually your gradle file shows an error, and says that using different versions could cause runtime issues. Cheers

Comment: I also needed to make  mobile/wear gradel use the same versions and same GMS services versions  gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.2 &     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'& 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'

Answer (score 3):

If, like me, you have all your firebase things using the same ver. be sure to check all google related ones too.

For me I had:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.0.1'
```

and:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
```

The issue for me wasn't that the firebase didn't match across themselves but that they didn't match the google ver. used for ads.

Changing all my firebase ones to use 10.2.1 solved the issue for me.

So make sure all the firebase ones match the other google ones.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is occur because dependency version mismatch means if use all the library firebase related with unique version like following way.

Wrong way :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
```

Right way :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this too, had both the play-services and firebase on the same version **10.2.0** and still got the exceptions. It was:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0"
```

I eventually just upgraded to **10.2.1**

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1"
```

and the exceptions were gone!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the firebase dependencies ....

this is a version compatibility issue

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

}
```

mine was a problem with firebase-ui version 1.2.0

then i have changed it with 1.0.1 that matches the other versions of firebase.

for more visit this page....

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when upgrading to Android Studio v3 and upgraded SDKs.
Fix consisted in app/Build.gradle to switch to 11.4.2 version:

compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2"

Into main Build.gradle
  Move to 3.1.1 version and add maven url

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
  maven {
      url 'https://maven.google.com'
  }
```

See https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.0.*/installation/android#4.-Install-modules