# Firebase realtime database dependency stops app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't understand where have i gone wrong in setting up firebase realtime database. I have followed the steps given on firebase docs and hence don't understand why this issue rose. Can't figure what's gone wrong??

My crash log :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: co.stemapps.alpha, PID: 16807
                                                                   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzeq(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzalp; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzalp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalp' appears in /data/data/co.stemapps.alpha/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-database-9.2.1_4a374bd9658b1411c8c3a3826ddeec88e7022694-classes.dex)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1730)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1705)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5039)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4634)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4574)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.stemapps.alpha"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: The same call stack was reported for [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732364/firebase-database-dependency-crashes-app), which was caused by inconsistent versions of dependencies.  Your versions are consistent.  Have you tried doing a clean and rebuilding?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Anyways it just got solved i uninstalled the app from my phone and reinstalled it and it worked. Thanks for the help!