# Android App + Firebase initializations fail

Tags: android, firebase

for my Android App, I need firebase integrated. So I followed the google tutorial.

now I am always getting after implementing firebase

```
E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
```

when I run the App (on Real Device and Simulation)

Already saw that: [Firebase database dependency crashes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732364/firebase-database-dependency-crashes-app)
but he is working with old versions...

So my dependencies look like this:

```
   dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here the projects gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'



    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

does anybody know what to do to get rid of this initalization problem?

Comment: Do FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); For more info- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977847/make-sure-to-call-firebaseapp-initializeappcontext-first-in-android

Comment: tried to initalize in mainActivity but it still the same...

Comment: Instead of MainActivity, try to initialise it in your app class

Comment: Please add the content of the other build.gradle file and please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo code added

Comment: Have you tried to comment `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'`? Does it work?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes I did. see edit.

Comment: @JohannesDey And what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of adding "com.google.android.gms:play-services:", identify what is needed from playservices. Because play services is stuffed with 22 packages and you might not using all of it. This will bloat the apk size and you might cross [65K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) in your project.

I'd advice, you go through this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) and pick necessary things you need from playservices.

Comment: thanks for the hint. this made my app work again. but the issue with {E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.} is still there

Comment: can you paste snap of your project structure, are you missing google-services.json file